# Yii2 - left join on multiple condition

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have three tables with the following relations,

```
  ------- 1        0..* ------------
 |Product|-------------|Availability|
  -------               ------------
    1 |
      |
    1 |
  --------
 |MetaData|
  --------
```

my raw sql looks like this

```
SELECT p.ID FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN availability a ON a.productID=p.ID 
          AND a.start>=DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
LEFT JOIN meta_data m ON m.ID=p.meta_dataID
WHERE a.ID IS NULL
AND m.published_state=1;
```

That is, find each `Product` with a `MetaData.published_state` equal to `1` and with no `Availability` such that `Availability.start` more than 7 days from `now()`.

I'm trying to accomplish the same using `ActiveRecord` methods, using something like the following,

```
$products = Product::find()
            ->joinWith('metaData')
            ->joinWith('availability')
            ->onCondition(['>=', 'availability.start', strtotime('+7 days')])
            ->where(['is', 'availability.ID', NULL])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'meta_data.published_state', 1])
            ->all();
```

however, this is returning no results. Using `Connection::createCommand()` to run the raw sql returns the rows I'd expect so there is no issue with the data.

I suspect the issue is being caused by the `join` conditions and the `where` conditions 'bleeding' into each other; both join and where being applied to either the joining or the where rather than separately.

How can I output the actual sql query being run? this is in an action being called from a console controller.

How can I alter my code to return the desired `Products`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe this one is better solution. Instead of using Raw queries like `leftJoin` you should complement your `joinWith` relations with `andOnCondition` (which adds needed where conditions into your join statement).

```
$products = Product::find()
    ->joinWith(['metaData' => function (ActiveQuery $query) {
        return $query
            ->andWhere(['=', 'meta_data.published_state', 1]);
    }])
    ->joinWith(['availability' => function (ActiveQuery $query) {
        return $query
            ->andOnCondition(['>=', 'availability.start', strtotime('+7 days')])
            ->andWhere(['IS', 'availability.ID', NULL]);
    }])
    ->all();
```

In addition it looks cleaner when you write `where` clauses inside relations. It works the same as writing it outside (if I'm not wrong), but when refactoring your query, you can easily delete the whole relation without forgetting relation conditions outside.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. Very very Helpful. Just note `ActiveQuery` namespace is `\yii\db\ActiveQuery`

Comment: I should also add that in case you want to pass parameters you can do the following `->joinWith(['yourRelations' => function($query) use($param1) { ... } `

Answer (score 16):

Just use like below condition.

```
$query = Product::find()
 ->leftJoin('availability', 'availability.productID=product.ID  AND a.start>=DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)')
 ->leftJoin('meta_data', 'meta_data.ID=product.meta_dataID')
 ->where(['is', 'availability.ID', NULL])
 ->andWhere(['=', 'meta_data.published_state', 1])
 ->all();
```

Comment: it gives data for only product, all not from availability and meta_data. How can i show both of them in result.

Comment: you are using raw leftJoins instead of Yii2 relations. It is better to complement the current relation with additional where condition

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.ID FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN availability a ON a.productID=p.ID 
          AND a.start>=DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
LEFT JOIN meta_data m ON m.ID=p.meta_dataID
WHERE a.ID IS NULL
AND m.published_state=1';

$products = Product::findBySql($sql);
```

Yii Active Record has a [`findBySql($sql)`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#findBySql()-detail) method that allows you to run and get the data from database using a raw SQL query. It helps a lot when you got confused with Yii's query method or when your query get more complicated to be ran with Yii as in your case I suppose.

So basically, in above block of codes, you just put your raw SQL query to a variable called `$sql`, and use it as the parameter value of `findBySql()` method.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation for how this code works and how it solves the question.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it helps.