# Left Join with multiple condition Yii2 error

Tags: yii2

according to this thread [Yii2 - left join on multiple condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512457/yii2-left-join-on-multiple-condition)
i create sql function in Mfwpcontroller like this :

```
use Yii;
use app\models\Mfwp;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\MfwpSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\Response;



    public function actionLists($id)    
    {           
    $posts = Mfwp::find()
    ->joinWith(['user' => function (ActiveQuery $query) {
        return $query
            ->andOnCondition(['=', 'user.id', 'mfwp.id_mfwp'])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'mfwp.id', $id]);
    }])        
    ->asArray()        
    ->all();
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
    return $posts;


   }
```

and this is my model in mfwp

```
public function getMfwp()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'id_mfwp']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getSmWps()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SmWp::className(), ['id_sm_wp' => 'id']);
}
```

when i try to execute by accessing http://bla-bla.oke/mfwp/lists?id=1, its show an error

Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException
app\models\Mfwp has no relation named "user".
↵
Caused by: Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: app\models\Mfwp::getuser()

and this is my database structure https://imge.to/i/vE2nWC

so whats wrong with my code..thank you for your advice

Comment: 'user' in your example is the table or the relation name?

Comment: user is a table name..

Comment: ok so that is your problem. In Yii there you need to put a relation name. So user must be a relation. Check the internet how to setup a relation, and you can name the relation 'user'

Comment: Thx my man finnaly i found the answer..its about relation name..user in model come from yii migration..i generated 1 model again using name pejabat before. So i changed name relation in pejabat model and correct name relation in mfwp model..and its work..iam new in yii2..

Comment: define a relation name `getUser()` inside you `Mpwp` model

Comment: Thx mr aslam.. I ve already found the answer by correcting relation name in controller..now iam know exactly how one/many relation works in yii2..